# how can i bring bottom menu in sidebar

Tags: html, css

I am facing problem with bottom menu bar. I want nothing in the bottom menu bar. All the content and functionality which is same horizontally, I want to place vertically on the left side in a green space.

**My HTML file:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Welcome to Cctvcart store</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header_wrap">
        <div class="header_top_wrap">
            <div class="header_top">
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--end of header top wrap -->
        <div class="header_bottom_wrap">
            <div class="header_bottom">
                <ul class="bottom_menu">

                    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Company</a>
                        <ul class="submenu">
                            <li><a href="#">About Cctvcart</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">New Releases</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                    <li class="dropdown"><a  href="#">Products</a>
                        <ul class="submenu">
                            <li><a href="#">DVR & Kits</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Seurity Cameras</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Spy Camreas</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Wireless & IP Cameras</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Accessories</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Mini Video</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Services</a>
                        <ul class="submenu">
                            <li><a href="#">Warranty Registration</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Professional Installation</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Support</a>
                        <ul class="submenu">
                            <li><a href="#">Support Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Support Center</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Customer Feedback</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Contact Tech Support</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">DVR DDNS Portal</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Multimedia</a>
                        <ul class="submenu">
                            <li><a href="#">Cctvcart Videos</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Podcasts</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Video Instruction Guides</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>

            </div>
        </div>
        <!--end of bottom  wrap -->
    </div>
    <!--end of header wrap -->
    <div class="main_wrap">
        <div class="main">
        </div>
        <!--end of main  -->
    </div>
    <!--end of main wrap -->
    <div class="footer_wrap">
        <footer></footer>
    </div>
    <!--end of footer wrap -->
</body>
</html>
```

**My CSS file:**

```
* {
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px;
 }
 .header_wrap {
   width: 100%;
   height: 160px;
   background: red;
   position: relative;
 }
 .main_wrap {
   width: 100%;
   height: 1475px;
   background: green;
 }
 .footer_wrap {
   width: 100%;
   height: 325px;
   background: aqua;
 }
 .main {
   width: 1000px;
   height: 100%;
   background: blue;
   margin: auto;
 }
 footer {
   width: 1000px;
   height: 100%;
   background: aqua;
   margin: auto;
 }
 .header_top_wrap {
   width: 100%;
   height: 23px;
   background: #ccc;
 }
 .header_bottom_wrap {
   width: 100%;
   height: 40px;
   background: #06F;
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0px;
   left: 0px;
 }
 .header_top {
   width: 1000px;
   height: 100%;
   background: purple;
   margin: auto;
 }
 .header_bottom {
   width: 1000px;
   height: 100%;
   background: black;
   margin: auto;
 }
 .bottom_menu > li {
   display: inline-block;
 }
 .bottom_menu a
 {
     font-family: Impact, Haettenschweiler, "Franklin Gothic Bold", "Arial Black", sans-serif;
     color: #fff;

 }
 .bottom_menu > li >a {
   display: block;
   text-decoration: none;


   padding: 0px 30px;
   height: 40px;
   line-height: 35px;
   text-align: center;
 }
.bottom_menu > li:hover >a
{
    background:#fff;
    color:#151716;
}
.submenu  a:active, .submenu  a:visited{
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  z-index: 21;
}
.submenu {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  width:200px;
  height:auto;
  background:white;
  list-style:none;
}
.dropdown:hover > .submenu{
  display: block;

}
.submenu>li>a
{
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:42px;
    background:black;
    text-decoration:none;
    line-height:58px;
    padding-left:20px;
    border:1px dashed white;
}
```

Here is the JSFiddle :

https://jsfiddle.net/zwjpawug/embedded/result/

http://jsfiddle.net/zwjpawug/

Comment: Please show a http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and clearly state what your code shows instead of what you want.

Comment: @panky are you looking like this.? **http://jsfiddle.net/zwjpawug/1/** or what.?

Comment: yes like this but its coming in middle.it should come left side of screen.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**HTML CODE**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Welcome to Cctvcart store</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="header_wrap">
    <div class="header_top_wrap">
      <div class="header_top">
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--end of header top wrap -->
    <div class="header_bottom_wrap">

    </div>
    <!--end of bottom  wrap -->
  </div>
  <!--end of header wrap -->
  <div class="main_wrap">
  <div class="header_bottom">
  <ul class="bottom_menu">
          <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Company</a>

          <ul class="submenu">
              <li><a href="#">About Cctvcart</a>
              </li>
                       <li><a href="#">New Releases</a>
              </li>
                       <li><a href="#">Contact us</a>
              </li>
          </ul>
           </li>
          <li class="dropdown"><a  href="#">Products</a>
            <ul class="submenu">
              <li><a href="#">DVR & Kits</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Seurity Cameras</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Spy Camreas</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Wireless & IP Cameras</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Accessories</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Mini Video</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>

           <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Services</a>
           <ul class="submenu">
              <li><a href="#">Warranty Registration</a>
              </li>
                   <li><a href="#">Professional Installation</a>
              </li>
              </ul>

           </li>
          <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Support</a>
           <ul class="submenu">
              <li><a href="#">Support Home</a>
              </li>

              <li><a href="#">Support Center</a>
              </li>
                          <li><a href="#">Customer Feedback</a>
              </li>
                          <li><a href="#">Contact Tech Support</a>
              </li>

                          <li><a href="#">DVR DDNS Portal</a>
              </li>

          </ul>

          </li>
           <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Multimedia</a>

            <ul class="submenu">
              <li><a href="#">Cctvcart Videos</a>
              </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Podcasts</a>
              </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Video Instruction Guides</a>
              </li>
              </ul>

          </li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    <div class="main">
    </div>
    <!--end of main  -->
  </div>
  <!--end of main wrap -->
  <div class="footer_wrap">
    <footer></footer>
  </div>
  <!--end of footer wrap -->
  </body>
  </html>
```

**CSS CODE**

```
   * {
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px;
 }
 .header_wrap {
   width: 100%;
   height: 160px;
   background: red;
   position: relative;
 }
 .main_wrap {
   width: 100%;
   height: 1475px;
   background: green;
 }
 .footer_wrap {
   width: 100%;
   height: 325px;
   background: aqua;
 }
 .main {
   width: 1000px;
   height: 100%;
   background: blue;
   margin: auto;
   position:relative;
   top:-200px;
   z-index:10;
 }
 footer {
   width: 1000px;
   height: 100%;
   background: aqua;
   margin: auto;
 }
 .header_top_wrap {
   width: 100%;
   height: 23px;
   background: #ccc;
 }
 .header_bottom_wrap {
   width: 100%;
   height: 40px;
   background: #06F;
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0px;
   left: 0px;
 }
 .header_top {
   width: 1000px;
   height: 100%;
   background: purple;
   margin: auto;
 }
 .header_bottom {
   width: 175px;
   /*height: 100%;
   margin: auto;*/
   background: black;
   z-index:1;
 }
 .bottom_menu {
     width:150px; 
 }
 .bottom_menu > li {
   /*display: inline-block;*/
 }
 .bottom_menu a
 {
     font-family: Impact, Haettenschweiler, "Franklin Gothic Bold", "Arial Black", sans-serif;
     color: #fff;

 }
 .bottom_menu > li >a {
   display: block;
   text-decoration: none;
   padding: 0;
   height: 40px;
   line-height: 35px;
   text-align: center;
   width:150px;
 }
.bottom_menu > li:hover >a
{
    background:#fff;
    color:#151716;
    width:170px;
}
.submenu  a:active, .submenu  a:visited{
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  z-index: 21;
}
.submenu {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left:160px;
  display: none;
  width:auto;
  height:auto;
  background:white;
  list-style:none;
  z-index:100;
  margin-top:-40px;
}
.dropdown:hover > .submenu{
  display: block;

}
.submenu>li>a
{
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:42px;
    background:black;
    text-decoration:none;
    line-height:58px;
    padding-left:20px;
    border:1px dashed white;
}
```

It may help you.

Comment: provide me screenshot or elaborate your requirement

Comment: i want to keep bottom menu bar contents vertically in place green color

Comment: Currently, it is in green color vertically.